# Winning check and playagain c# tictactoe

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

i have 3 problems :
1- The "letsPlay" button when pressed the first time gives me oImage wherever i press but afterwards works just fine.
2-The Winner() method isn't working ... it does nothing.
3-How to reset my grid background because i couldn't find any result about it.

Ok so here is the xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button x:Name="letsPlay" Content="Let's Start!" Click="letsPlay_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="turnText" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Margin="302,10,0,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="Turn = X" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Foreground="#FFFB0707" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="theGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="cell9" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell9_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell8_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell7_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell4_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell1_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell5_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell2_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell6_Tapped"/>
        <Image x:Name="cell3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/Logo.png" Tapped="cell3_Tapped"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Now for the code running behind :

```
bool turn = true;
    int moveCount1 = 0;
    BitmapImage xImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/X.png"));
    BitmapImage oImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/O.png"));
    BitmapImage nullImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/Logo.png"));
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        theGrid.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        turnText.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.Winner();
    }
```

The letsPlay button and the Reset() method:

```
    private void letsPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
        }
void Reset()
        {
            theGrid.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            turnText.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            turn = true;
            turnText.Text = "Turn = X";
            moveCount1 = 0;
            cell1.Source = nullImage;
            cell1.Tapped += cell1_Tapped;
            cell2.Source = nullImage;
            cell2.Tapped += cell2_Tapped;
            cell3.Source = nullImage;
            cell3.Tapped += cell3_Tapped;
            cell4.Source = nullImage;
            cell4.Tapped += cell4_Tapped;
            cell5.Source = nullImage;
            cell5.Tapped += cell5_Tapped;
            cell6.Source = nullImage;
            cell6.Tapped += cell6_Tapped;
            cell7.Source = nullImage;
            cell7.Tapped += cell7_Tapped;
            cell8.Source = nullImage;
            cell8.Tapped += cell8_Tapped;
            cell9.Source = nullImage;
            cell9.Tapped += cell9_Tapped;
        }
```

This is a cell code example:

```
private void cell9_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (turn)
        {
            cell9.Source = xImage;
            turn = !turn;
            turnText.Text = "Turn = O";
        }
        else
        {
            cell9.Source = oImage;
            turn = !turn;
            turnText.Text = "Turn = X";
        }
        cell9.Tapped -= cell9_Tapped;
        moveCount1++;
    }
```

And Finally this is the Winner() method:

```
public void Winner()
    {
        if (
            (cell1.Source == xImage && cell2.Source == cell1.Source && cell3.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell4.Source == xImage && cell5.Source == cell4.Source && cell6.Source == cell4.Source) ||
            (cell7.Source == xImage && cell8.Source == cell7.Source && cell9.Source == cell7.Source) ||
            (cell1.Source == xImage && cell5.Source == cell1.Source && cell9.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell3.Source == xImage && cell5.Source == cell3.Source && cell7.Source == cell3.Source) ||
            (cell1.Source == xImage && cell4.Source == cell1.Source && cell7.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell2.Source == xImage && cell5.Source == cell2.Source && cell8.Source == cell2.Source) ||
            (cell3.Source == xImage && cell6.Source == cell3.Source && cell9.Source == cell3.Source)
            )
        {
            ImageBrush xWins1 = new ImageBrush();
            xWins1.ImageSource = xImage;
            theGrid.Background = xWins1;
        }
        else if (
            (cell1.Source == oImage && cell2.Source == cell1.Source && cell3.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell4.Source == oImage && cell5.Source == cell4.Source && cell6.Source == cell4.Source) ||
            (cell7.Source == oImage && cell8.Source == cell7.Source && cell9.Source == cell7.Source) ||
            (cell1.Source == oImage && cell5.Source == cell1.Source && cell9.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell3.Source == oImage && cell5.Source == cell3.Source && cell7.Source == cell3.Source) ||
            (cell1.Source == oImage && cell4.Source == cell1.Source && cell7.Source == cell1.Source) ||
            (cell2.Source == oImage && cell5.Source == cell2.Source && cell8.Source == cell2.Source) ||
            (cell3.Source == oImage && cell6.Source == cell3.Source && cell9.Source == cell3.Source)
            )
        {
            ImageBrush oWins1 = new ImageBrush();
            oWins1.ImageSource = oImage;
            theGrid.Background = oWins1;
        }
        else if (moveCount1 == 9)
        {
            ImageBrush tie1 = new ImageBrush();
            tie1.ImageSource = nullImage;
            theGrid.Background = tie1;
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate any help you guys can give and if you require any more details just ask ahead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code will look much nicer if you'll access the cells as an array and implement  `checkHorizon(int column)`/`checkVerticals(int row)`/`checkCross(bool isRightToLeft)` functions - one that recieves a number, and checks the selected horizontal/vertical/crossed line for a winner, and returns a value. Since i`m not sure if there's a simple way to access a gridView as an array in wpf, here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) for a way that'd work from C# if you insert the 9 cells manually.

Your first problem is about a [button OnClick event not firing on the first try.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Button%20not%20firing) There's a lot of reasons this problem could happen - I remmber when I used to program for ASP.NET this sort of problems had to do with the page_load and ASP page life cycle. Take a look at [the equivallent for wpf,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx)  and let me know if it solved your problem

Your second problem is pretty much similar straightforward. You want your `Winner()` function to change the images if I get this properly. I think the problem again has to do with the object lifecycle - The problem is the object is allready loaded to the page, so in order to view the changes you have to *refresh the page* after the changes.

And then there's the third problem, which is probably the solution for the first two. How to refresh a page you ask? I borrowed the syntax from [Another source](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/3789/how-to-redirect-one-page-to-another) since I remmber the context from ASP. the solution is redirecting the user to your page, and then the grid will initially reload itself. You can do that like so:

```
const string pageName = "insert your page name here";
/*Insert some other code here*/
public static redirect(string directionName)
{
    Response.Redirect(directionName+".aspx");
}
/* Insert some more code here */
```

and whenever there's a change in the gridview you can simply use `redirect(pageName);`

Good luck, let me know if there are any further problems you couldn't solve about this :)

Comment: I kind of understood what you are talking about ... but i don't know how to use or implement them ( very low experience ). So if you could assist me using a social media ( well if you are free ofc), i am available. And thanks for your support.

Comment: @ElieSaad If you really have to, we can talk over skype; However talking here has it's benefits where others can help us when we get stuck, i also dont know everything :) 
However , if it's just about applying the concepts i wrote here to your project - i'll help you.

Comment: add me: saad.elie1
when we finish from talking and clearing the problems we can show them over here.